# Has anyone tricked the Apple Configurator to work with non VPP redemption codes?

Tags: ios-appstore, mobile-device-management, apple-configurator, volume-purchase-program

I wonder if anyone has had success or failure in attempting to use the Apple Configurator with normal gifted app redemption codes. The FAQ clearly states that you must be in the Volume Purchase Program (VPP) to import a spreadsheet from the VPP portal - however, I wonder if it would be possible to assemble a DIY spreadsheet with valid gifted apps for use.

[Apple Configurator: Using Volume Purchase Program (VPP) Redemption Codes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5188)

My guess is no, but figured perhaps someone may have already tried this.

Comment: Configuration 1.0.1 now allows you to use normal redemption codes to install on one device.

Comment: I don't see this helping anyone, so I'm closing it as too-localized. Feel free to flag it if you feel it needs a better answer or should be re-opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was only necessary with version 1.0 of the configurator.

Version 1.0.1 (110) allows more codes to be used than just VPP generated ones.